# Im using camel proxy how can i send headers in interface as parameter

Tags: java, apache-camel

Im using camel proxy to call an endpoint in camel say direct:say.

```
public interface xyz{ 
public void sayhello(String body,??????); 
}
```

??? i want to set headers or send headers can any one help with an example in binding interface. 
Thanks 
Saitsh

Comment: not sure about that. You can likely achieve the same thing with @EndpointInject - https://camel.apache.org/pojo-producing.html

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at http://camel.apache.org/parameter-binding-annotations.html. One nifty example:

```
 public void sayhello(@Header("user") String user, @Body String body, Exchange exchange) {
     exchange.getIn().setBody(body + "MyBean");
 }
```

Beside that following annotations are available:

- `@Headers` to bind to the Map of the inbound message headers
- `@OutHeaders` to bind to the Map of the outbound message headers

Answer (score 0):

Very quick leads...

look at http://camel.apache.org/bean and http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html

```
JndiContext context = new JndiContext();
context.bind("xyz", new XyzImp());

CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(context);
```

then you can call

```
to("bean:xyz?method=sayhello(${body}, ${headers})")
```

or you can add annotation to you interface

```
sayhello(@Body String body,@Headers Map headers);
```

and then

```
to("bean:xyz?method=sayhello(*, *)")
```

or

```
to("bean:xyz?method=sayhello")
```

should be enough...

The BIG question is, how do you instantiate your `xyz` interface? Is it singleton or you need a fresh instance for each message or one per thread? But that would be different question :)

Answer (score 0):

### Camel 2.16+

Use native proxy parameter binding as described here: http://camel.apache.org/using-camelproxy.html ("What is send on the Message" section).

### Previous versions

There no standard way of parameter binding for Camel route proxy. Only one String argument can be bound to exchange body.

But you can create custom implementation of **InvocationHandler** which will extend Camel core **AbstractCamelInvocationHandler** class and provide desired parameter binding by overriding of **invokeWithbody**(...) method.

Check Camel ProxyUtil.createProxyObject(...) method to understand how proxy object is initiated.